# How to add a view programatically to a FrameLayout extended in another class?

Tags: android

I've a View class that creates circles:

```
public class PieItem extends View{


        private final float x;
        private final float y;
        private final int r;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


        public PieItem(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
            super(context);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        }


}
```

Edit: 
I want to fit it into a framelayout programtically and then recreate it in activities:

This is me extending a Framelayout:

```
 public class PieMenu extends FrameLayout{

    private Context _context;
    public PieMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void addPieMenu(int x, int y){
        Toast.makeText(_context, "text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        PieItem pieView = new PieItem(_context,x,y,1);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lyp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        pieView.setLayoutParams(lyp); 
        addView(pieView);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    PieMenu pieMenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pieMenu = new PieMenu(getApplicationContext());

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                pieMenu.addPieMenu(x,y);
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
    return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way In your PieMenu

```
public class PieMenu extends FrameLayout{

public PieMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();

}

private void init(){

   PieItem pieView = new PieItem(context,x,y,r);

   addView(pieView);
}
```

Comment: How do I call this in an activity, so that on touch of a canvas, a PieItem would be created?

Comment: Step 1: Add an instance of <PieMenu> in your layout file for your activity
Step 2: In your activity, on Click of your button , call a method <PieMenuObjectInLayout>.addPieItem(x,y,r);
Step 3: addPieItem(float x,float y,int r){
   PieItem pieView = new PieItem(context,x,y,r);
   addView(pieView);
   invalidate():
}

Comment: I just updated my code with changes but I still see no circle on touch. Even though the "toast" is being called.

Comment: in your activity_main.xml, add the following:
....
<com.package....PieMenu
android:id="@+id/pie"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"/>
..

Then in your onCreate change initalize of pieMenu to:
pieMenu =(PieMenu)findViewById(R.id.pie);

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue of the view not being displayed, but figured out the cause: you need to add the view (call addView()) not in the constructor, but after the view has finished inflating (onFinishInflate()). Here's a sample:

```
public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        View blackOverlay = new View(getContext());
        blackOverlay.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        blackOverlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        blackOverlay.setAlpha(0.2f);
        addView(blackOverlay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    public class PieMenu extends FrameLayout {

        public PieMenu(Context context) {
            super(context);

            PieItem pieView = new PieItem(context, x, y);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lyp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            pieView.setLayoutParams(lyp);
            addView(pieView);
        }
    }
```

You may need `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` to located the `PieItem`, then you can add `PieMenu` in `Activity` by call `addContentView(view, params)`.

Comment: You may need `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` to located the `pipeItem`, then you can add `PieMenu` in `Activity` by call `addContentView(view, params)`.